# Google authentication and authorization among their apps

Tags: security, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

Google provides a bunch of apps like Plus, Gmail, Docs, Reader, etc. Internally, these apps can talk to each other securely somehow to query information/data. I am wondering conceptually how Google implements this secured authentication and authorization among their apps internally. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

As I think all these apps working on separate sockets, by that mean all the applications working separately as well as security can be implemented there also.
.
Not pretty much assure about my answer, correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Application-to-application authentication for end users is implemented via [OAuth 2.0 service accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount). It is likely that the mechanism is reused internally as it fits the needs.